# How to check if the dates are not the same

Tags: php, date

I try to write a script that can calculate the difference between two dates, in days, and the `diff` does not behave as I need to.

More specific, lets say we have the following two date/times:

`2015-03-18 23:00`

`2015-03-19 02:00`

The actual time difference is four hours, and in this terms the `diff` works fine !

But what I like to know is, if the calendar date has been change, and what  is the actual difference.

So in the example above, the calendar dates having 1 day difference.

In the following example

`2015-03-18 23:00`

`2015-03-21 02:00`

I have three days difference. So how can I calculate this date difference ?

At the moment I use the following code:

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2009-10-11 23:30');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2009-10-12 02:30');

$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($interval);
echo "</pre>";
```

and the result is the following:

```
DateInterval Object
(
    [y] => 0
    [m] => 0
    [d] => 0
    [h] => 3
    [i] => 0
    [s] => 0
    [weekday] => 0
    [weekday_behavior] => 0
    [first_last_day_of] => 0
    [invert] => 0
    [days] => 0
    [special_type] => 0
    [special_amount] => 0
    [have_weekday_relative] => 0
    [have_special_relative] => 0
)
```

Is there any idea ? Thanks ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### A really simple solution

**Notice**: this will only work if the **days are in the same month**.

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2015-03-18 23:00');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2015-03-21 02:00');
$difference = $datetime2->format('d') - $datetime1->format('d'); //3
```

### Clean solution

You could remove everything from the date, but the year, month and day and use diff() as you already did.

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2015-03-18 23:00');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2015-03-21 02:00');
$datetime1modified = new DateTime($datetime1->format('Y-m-d'));
$datetime2modified = new DateTime($datetime2->format('Y-m-d'));
$difference = $datetime1modified->diff($datetime2modified)->d; //3
```

Comment: Great ! That's works. Thanks a lot for your answer. I will upvote you in about 8 minutes ;)

Answer (score 1):

you surely could use a function like this:

```
$time1 = strtotime("2008-12-13 10:42:00");
$time2 = strtotime("2010-10-20 08:10:00");

$diff = $time2-$time1;
// the difference in int. then you can divide by 60,60,24 and 
// so on to get the h:m:s out of it
```

or if you more into the build in php functions then something like this might suit your needs:

```
$date_a = new DateTime('2010-10-20 08:10:00');
$date_b = new DateTime('2008-12-13 10:42:00');

$interval = date_diff($date_a,$date_b);

echo $interval->format('%h:%i:%s');
```

best regards.

Comment: This script does not work in my case, and I suppose you have not understand my question. Anyway, thanks a lot for your participation ! :)

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is remove the Time from each of the dates and then calculate.

example:

```
$datetime1 ='2009-10-11 23:30';
$datetime2 = '2009-10-12 02:30';

$date1_explode = explode($datetime1,' ');
$date1_explode = explode($datetime1,' ');

$date = $date1_explode[1];
$date = $date2_explode[1];
$date1 = new DateTime($datetime1);
$date2 = new DateTime($datetime1);

$interval = $date1->diff($date2);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($interval);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, but I will choose the @Escobear answer because it has better implementation. Just to know I just up vote your answer ;) :)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about the hours and want to know only if the date changed you can try to `diff` the dates after you set them to the same hour:

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2009-10-11 23:30');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2009-10-12 02:30');

// Work on duplicates to not change the original objects if they are needed later
$date1 = clone $datetime1;
$date2 = clone $datetime2;

// Set the same hour on both $date1 and $date2
$date1->setTime(0, 0, 0);
$date2->setTime(0, 0, 0);

// Now you can simply compare $date1 to $date2 to see if they are equal
if ($date1 == $date2) {
    echo('$datetime1 and $datetime2 are on the same date.');
} else {
    echo('$datetime1 and $datetime2 are on different dates.');
}

// Or you can compute the difference
$diff = $date2->diff($date1);
// and format it as you like
echo('There are '.$diff->format('%d').' days between '.$date1.' and '.$date2);
```